# Perform JavaScript on submit of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I use a JavaScript to load new pages on my webpagepage. looks like this:

```
function loadpage(page,div) {
            $.get(page, function(data) {
                $(div).html(data)
            });
        };
```

So when i submit my form, I want to use that function to load the php-page you normally would set as your "action" attribute in the form-tag. So how do I get the form to POST or GET(doesen't really matter) all its content and use the function.

Now, when I write:

```
<form action="javascript:loadpage('bla.php','#content');" method="post">
...
</form>
```

it loads bla.php the way i want it to but no data is being passed byt the POST...

Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: unfortunately your problem is really hard to understand. Are you looking for ways to use the jquery post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method, you would do it as follows:

**Javascript:**

```
function loadpage(page, div, form) {
    var GETdata = '';

    if ( form ) GETdata = $(form).serialize();

    $.get(page, GETdata, function(data) {
        $(div).html(data)
    });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:loadpage('bla.php','#content', this);" method="post">
...
</form>
```

---

A better way would be to use non-obtrusive Javascript. Remove the inline javascript:

```
<form id="theForm" action="" method="post">
...
</form>
```

and bind your event handler from within your Javascript code:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadpage('bla.php','#content', this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

see [form.onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_onsubmit) event

Comment: i've tried that, but what do i set as "action" then? If I leave action empty the bla.php wont load... I need that. It somehow overrides the script.

Comment: While I commend you for supplying a link to relevant documentation I would have chosen a different resource since w3schools often lacks the carefull explanation new programmers need to get things working for them in an acceptable way. Try [sitepoint instead for instance](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onsubmit). Even better is directing someone to a more commonly accepted way doing things like Joseph did.